# Javacard converter specifications

Tags: smartcard, javacard

In the attempt of reversing a javacard cap file into a class file , I am looking for a converter specifications. So far I found 'only' a very partial formal model in PVS. The javacard vm specifications describes in detail the cap files format but do not detail the optimization and operation made by the converter. There are several books and resources who describes some aspects of how the converter transforms class into cap but I could not find a comprehensive documentation.Sun(Oracle)'s documentation do not describes the conversion mechanism and the cap file format specification is no enough to understand how to reconstitute a class file .Is there a document where class to cap file conversion is explained and detailed ?

Answer (score 2):

I did not found the converter's specs but I figured it out that the javacard jdk3 normalizer could be used as cap to class conversion